# What benefits would adding controllers/models/basically everything to their own namespace have?

Tags: php, laravel

The company I work for has requested that for an application (Laravel) we're developing to add controllers/models/repositories/validators to their own namespace (\Company\Whatever). I don't have a problem doing so but I'm curious as to what the benefits might be.

I would think that to do this I would simply autoload a custom name space (app/Company/Whatever) and create a new controller/model/whatnot directory structure under this.

Comment: This question is probably going to be closed (not a good fit for this site), but namespaces have a few benefits: Less/no nameconflicts: each namespace can have a custom, extended `LogicException`, handled by a designated handler. Organized code == maintainable code. Namespaces enforce your project files to be stored consistently. Easier testing, better IDE autocompletion and warnings. In an namespaced project, each class starts with a series of `use Some\Namespace\Class` statements: at a glance, everyone knows what the dependencies of a class are

Comment: Namespaces, in PHP at least, aren't as powerful/useful as they are in languages like C++, but they are important as your project grows. Just think back to those pre-namespace days, where classes were called `LibName_Service_Connection_Base`, now we write `Base`, if we're in the same namespace, or `use LibName\Service\Connection\Base;` once, and use `Base` throughout the code... do not underestimate laziness, it's a factor

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem any particular SE site that this would be a good ask on?

Comment: webapplications possibly, but there are some napespace-related questions on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) already: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221524/pros-and-cons-of-namespaces-vs-include-require-in-php seems to answer this question for you, voting to close

Comment: Not a good fit, [question exists on programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221524/pros-and-cons-of-namespaces-vs-include-require-in-php)

Comment: If your company uses a lot of 3rd party libraries, this would be a very good idea as there wouldn't be much of a chance of having any conflicts with class names.

Comment: We're not using all that many - not any that I would see as a potential conflict (ie: Ardent). We do have "events" which will conflict with Laravel's Event class, so there's that I suppose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between PSR-0 and PSR-4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few benefits to doing this.

1.) PSR-0/PSR-4 Autoloading

If you have a vendor namespace, then you can use PSR-0 or PSR-4 which makes autoloading insanely easy. You can just put this in your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/src/"
    }
},
```

2.) Collision Avoidance

Theoretically *your* code should be ok hogging the global namespace as everything else *should* be in its own namespace, but this is PHP and a) PHP itself doesn't use namespaces for any core classes b) not everyone out there is distributing their code under a namespace either. In 2014 this is much much **much** better than it was in 2010, but it is still potentially an issue.

There are probably some other reasons, but these two do it for me.