# Use Symfony2 Validator Annotations outside of Core

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

How do you configure Symfony2 Validator to use annotations outside of Core?

In core you would do the following:

```
$container->loadFromExtension('framework', array(
  'validation' => array(
    'enable_annotations' => true,
  ),
));
```

Taken from: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#configuration

For now to make validation work the rules are set within the method loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata), it works but I prefer annotations.

Example Entity with validation annotations and alternative php method to set validation rules:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Repository\FooRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 */
class Foo {


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="bar")
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="integer",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
     * )
     */
    protected $bar;


    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('bar', new Assert\Type(array(
            'type'    => 'integer',
            'message' => 'The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.',
        )));
    }    
}
```

**Update 1**

The issue now seems to be that the annotations are not being autoloaded correctly.

I load the annotations in to the namespace with:

```
\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry
::registerAutoloadNamespace("Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\\", __DIR__.'/vendor/symfony/validator');
```

Then when it tries to autoload the annotations it looks for `/vendor/symfony/validator/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/Length.php` which does not exist.   The file is actually located at `/vendor/symfony/validator/Constraints/Length.php`

I could create a `registerLoader()` but would rather fix the code.  When using Validator within Symfony2 Core that file location would be correct.

How do I make it autoload correctly or get composer to install Symfony2 components to the same location as core?

Comment: I have integrated Symfony\Validator to Nette\DI, you can [find some inspiration there](https://github.com/Symnedi/Validator/blob/master/src/DI/ValidatorExtension.php).

Comment: Did you had a look at https://github.com/symfony/Validator#usage , move a bit down to annotations. Please don't forget to download the doctrine/annotation library etc which are needed dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to register the Autoloader with AnnotationRegistry, so where ever you require vendor/autoload, for example bootstrap.php add the registerLoader().

```
//Composer libraries
$loader = require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);
```

Turns out the solution is quite straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer provides a solution without giving any explaination regarding the failure.

The reason is simple. The default annotation loader which is provided by the **Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry** only handle PSR-0 namespaces, while the Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints is a PSR-4 namespace. Thus, the loader fail to load the class. Registering the composer auloader with the **AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader** method solves the problem because that autoloader handle the PSR-4 namespaces.

You can refer to this question to get more detaits about PSR-0 and PSR-4 differences: [What is the difference between PSR-0 and PSR-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4)

Comment: Since I stumbled upon this issue I'd like to add, that Doctrine by default does not autoload **any** annotations outside it's own library. Default annotation engine specifies a single file indicating which annotations can be used (so it's not really in issue with PSR-0 or PSR-4).

See [Doctrine Configuration.php](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/6dcb97a/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L154)