# Symfony 2.8 Validator Component in a standalone project

Tags: php, validation, symfony, annotations

I'm trying to include the Symfony Validator Component in our small application. But I can't get it working. I think I put everything together but I always get an Exception.

```
AnnotationException in AnnotationException.php line 54:
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property UserEntity ::$username does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

But the Class exists and is auto-loaded. I tested it with: `AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader()`.

You can find the Code I'm using here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c44fc5a1068b13e9ca22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of how AnnotationRegistry load classes by namespace.

AnnotationRegistry tries to load `.../vendor/symfony/validator/Constraints/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/NotBlank.php`, not `.../vendor/symfony/validator/Constraints/NotBlank.php`.
[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33169258/5298034)

Use `AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader()`

Comment: Thank you! I changed my code to use the composer autoloader and it works!