# Require_once across different files, global scope

Tags: php, mysql, variables, scope, require-once

I've been learning PHP for a couple of days now and I came across a strange issue for me. I have two files :

`login.php` that stores database access data (user, pw, host, db)
`security.php` that have functions that manipulate strings/queries to prevent sql/xss injections and also stores salt prefix and suffix for password hashing.

Then I have my `index.php`, `register.php` and `signin.php`. My problem is : when I put `require_once '../login.php';` in `register.php` I can normally call a variable or function like *$var*. On the other hand, exactly the same pattern in `signin.php` is not working, PHP tells that that variables are not declared. I tried to do : `global $var`, and it was working but I have feeling that it's completely insecure.

1) What is the proper way to solve this problem?
2) Is it connected with app architecture?
3) Should all functions (and etc.) that use db connection be written in a single file?

Comment: See also [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 - **Create a php file , write all database connection into it**(example- db.php) 
Step 2 - **Include this php (db.php) wherever you have a database related operation.**

```
require 'db.php';  //add your database php file here..
```

This will be easy to organize, and minimizes errors when you migrate your app from one server to another
in php there is require and include. require is good since it will stop executing code if file is not available.

**Also this is easy to organize and minimizes the errors caused when migrating from one server to another**

Answer (score 0):

1. install [composer](https://getcomposer.org)
2. Put all your code into functions in classes with your [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) (as static functions if you must).
3. Save the classes like specified in [psr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4) in lib dir.
4. Create composer.json file as specified on composer website and include your lib dir as autoload as it says in composer docs.
5. require_once **projectroot**/vendor/autoload.php in your files.

Call your class methods (with namespace) instead of functions. Be lazy. Avoid require/include hell.