# Working directly with libraries instead of bundles in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

How can I use a library directly inside an existing Symfony2 project. I am, for instance, trying to add the [faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) library. I installed it via composer but I don't know how and where to put the code I need.

According to documentation:

```
// require the Faker autoloader
require_once '/path/to/Faker/src/autoload.php';
// alternatively, use another PSR-0 compliant autoloader (like the Symfony2 ClassLoader for instance)
```

What is a simple explanation of auto loader?
How to use a library directly without a bundle?
Is it a requirement for a library to have an `autoload.php` file so that it can be integrated inside a php project?
Where to put the above code?

Any links explaining such notions for newbies? Thank you very much for your usual guidance.

Comment: You can try reading the [spec](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), the [PHP Manual autoloading documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and the [Symfony `ClassLoader` component docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/index.html).

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I did for the symfony link with no luck from first reading, I will redo. Thanks for the php-fig link and php manual.

Comment: Autoloading itself is similar to path loading, except that the namespace for the class depicts where the class should be loaded from by describing a path mapping to directory mapping. This is so that you don't have to use `require` or `include` with actual paths. Here's also the [PSR-4 autoload spec](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), which supercedes PSR-0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need to config nothing. Faker library is PSR-4 (see composer.json, [this line](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/5ffe7db6c80f441f150fc88008d64e64af66634b/composer.json#L25)) compliant so just install it (through composer) and use the proper namespace. Symfony automatically loads [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) / [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) libraries/components. Like this:

```
<?php # src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Faker;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        var_dump($faker); die;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Helpful links:

- [Composer schema, "autoload" key](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)
- [What is the difference between PSR-0 and PSR-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4)
- [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)
- [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: How did you know Faker is PSR-4 compliant?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers If you see in Faker github project, file composer.json (line 23) describes the autoload mode as PSR-4, see: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/master/composer.json#L23

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Did you see?

Comment: thank you for your will to give detailed answers and help people. I fully understand now. wish you all the best