# psr-0 autoloading with composer not wotking, but it works perfectly with psr-4 autoloading

Tags: composer-php, psr-4, psr-0

I tried to autoload a file with PSR-0 ,but it is not auto loading that file. I tried the same file with PSR-4 auto loading. With PSR-4 it worked perfectly. Is there any difference in folder structure needed for PSR-0?

I couldn't make PSR-0 working even if keep the folder structure mentioned in [What is the difference between PSR-0 and PSR-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4)

Here is my folder structure.

```
Test
    --Package
        --Test.php
```

I have in `Test.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Test\Package;

class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "In Test class";
    }
}
```

and `composer.json` looks like

```
{
  "autoload": {

    "psr-0": {
            "Test\\Package\\": "Test/Package/"
             }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between PSR-0 and PSR-4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4)

Comment: @Wazelin

But i couldn't make PSR-0 working even if kept the folder structure that mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4

Here is my structure

Test
--Package
   --Test.php

Test.php ////////////////////////////////////////////

<?php
namespace Test\Package;

class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "In Test class";
    }
}

and composer.json looks like

{
  "autoload": {
 
    "psr-0": {
            "Test\\Package\\": "Test/Package/"
             }
  }
}

Comment: As you've described things they should be working. What are your actual class names and folder structure?

Comment: That is what i specified in the description :) @jwriteclub

Comment: Is the composer.json in the Test folder our outside the Test folder?

Comment: outside the Test folder @jwriteclub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-intuitively, [the composer documentation on PSR-0](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0) includes a partial path making it seem that PSR-0 requires a path to the package in order to load classes. In reality, PSR-0 constructs the path based on the package, so it only needs a path specified if the code lives inside a folder like `src/` or `lib/` that is *not* part of the namespace path. If the namespace based directory structure starts in the same directory as `composer.json`, then no path is required.

Assuming a directory structure as specified in the question, there's several ways to load this class using composer.

### PSR-0

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Test\\Package\\": "" }
  }
}
```

Note that even though the code lives in `Test/Package/`, this folder is **not** specified in PSR-0.

### PSR-4

For PSR-4 autoloading, the path to the package source must appear in the `composer.json` file.

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Test\\Package\\": "Test/Package/" }
  }
}
```

### Classmap

When the requirement exists to load classes which aren't organized into the typical namespace folder tree, it is also possible to simply specify a list of folders in which to search for classes using the `classmap` array.

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [ "Test/Package/" ]
  }
}
```

In general, however, using PSR-0 or PSR-4 will provide an easier experience, as the `classmap` approach requires every folder to be separately specified.