# composer autoloading sub-namespace from different directories

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I am working on an application, where a "meta" namespace has several sub-namespaces, placed in different directories. Take the example below:

```
$loader = require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$loader->set('Foo\Bar', realpath(__DIR__ . "/src/123/Foo/Bar"));
$loader->set('Foo\Baz', realpath(__DIR__ . "/src/abc/Foo/Baz"));
```

The "meta" namespace is of course `Foo`, and the sub-namespaces are `Bar` and `Baz`.

`composer` doesn't seem to be happy about it. The second namespace is ignored. Notice that the contents are stored in different folders below `src`; `123` and `abc`, respectively.

Is it not possible to assign sub-namespaces this way using `composer`?

I find it fairly difficult to find information about this corner case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible - with PSR-4 autoloader (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/, [What is the difference between PSR-0 and PSR-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868586/what-is-the-difference-between-psr-0-and-psr-4)):

```php
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->setPsr4('Foo\\Bar\\', realpath(__DIR__ . '/src/123/Foo/Bar'));
$loader->setPsr4('Foo\\Baz\\', realpath(__DIR__ . '/src/abc/Foo/Baz'));

$bar = new Foo\Bar\BarTest();
$baz = new Foo\Baz\BazTest();
```

Comment: Thank you! I did suspect ps4 would be the answer. :)