# php artisan throws FatalErrorException class not found

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-artisan

Laravel 4.1

It was working fine, till I reinstalled all the code again.
Did the **composer install** & it has been failing with the same error.

> > php artisan
> >     {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Idocrea8\Theme\Provider\ThemeServiceProvider' not found","file":"/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php","line":158}}

The app.config has this provider:

> 'Idocrea8\Theme\Provider\ThemeServiceProvider',

The workbench directory has a folder named **idocrea8** and seems to have all the files.
For example, the **composer.json** inside this folder :
**/workbench/idocrea8/theme**

```
{
    "name": "idocrea8/theme",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "iDocrea8",
            "email": "iDocrea8@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Idocrea8\\Theme": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

The **workbench/idocrea8** has the following directories:
- theme
- menu
- image
- hook

The actual **ThemeServiceProvider.php** is in this path - **/workbench/idocrea8/theme/src/Idocrea8/Theme/provider**

I'm not sure why the file cannot be found where it seems to be present..

Comment: it seems that the location is false

Comment: can you show the fully qualified name of ThemeServiceProvider?

Comment: First line of ThemeServiceProvider.php says : <?php namespace Idocrea8\Theme\Provider;  Is that what you were asking ?

Answer (score 0):

[psr-0 vs psr-4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24869629/6229548)

and [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0)

> #### For Psr-0
>
> Please note namespace declarations should end in \ to make sure the autoloader responds exactly.

may be you can try in composer json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Idocrea8\\Theme\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

or

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Idocrea8\\Theme\\": "src/Idocrea8/theme/"
        }
    }
```

Comment: o.k. and when I run "composer update" - I run it from the root or from thid directory - /workbench/idocrea8/theme ?

Comment: yes,when you run composer update it will find the composer configure file in current  path .

Comment: didn't work.... you see the "composer update" is failing at the root directory not here.

Comment: i am sorry , i don't know how to do .