# Composer PHP autoload not working

Tags: php, json, composer-php

for my WebPanel i created a libary, i can install it via composer without problems but when i want to implement my interface called View i got the following error message:

```
`2017/06/22 16:00:22 [error] 23179#23179: *120 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP 
message: PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'RaphaelScheinkoenig\WebLib\View' not 
found in /var/www/site/app/view/DashboardView.php on line 10" while reading 
response header from upstream, client: 88.xx.xxx.xxx, server: 
xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx, request: "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx"`
```

**Composer.json** of the Libary:

```
`{
 "name": "raphaelscheinkoenig/weblib",
 "description": "WebLib",
 "license": "MIT",
 "authors": [
{
  "name": "Raphael Scheinkoenig",
  "email": "scheinkoenig.raphael@gmail.com"
}
],
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
"php": ">=7.0.0"
},
"autoload": {
"psr-0": {
  "RaphaelScheinkoenig\\WebLib\\": "src/"
 }
 } 
 }`
```

Folder Tree of the libary: http://prntscr.com/fmwu6o

**View.php** of the libary:

```
`<?php
namespace RaphaelScheinkoenig\WebLib;
interface View{
public function getTitle():string;
public function getCSSPlugins():string;
public function getJsHeadScripts():string;
public function getContent():string;
public function getJSPlugins():string;
public function getActiveHeader():string;
public function getPluginInitialization():string;
public function getGoogleAnalytics():string;
public function getHeaderKey():string;
public function getFooter():string;
public function getPageHeader():string;
}`
```

**DasbordView.php** Implementation in the WebPanel:

```
require_once ($_SERVER["P_PATH"]."vendor/autoload.php");
class DashboardView implements RaphaelScheinkoenig\WebLib\View
{
public function getTitle():string{
    return "Dashboard";
}

public function getCSSPlugins():string{
    $str = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$_SERVER['P_PATH'].'assets/globals/css/plugins.css">';
    return $str;
}

public function getPageHeader():string{
    return "Dashboard";
}

public function getJsHeadScripts():string{
    return "";
}

public function getContent():string{
    // TODO: Implement getContent() method.
}

public function getJSPlugins():string{
    $str = '<script src="'.$_SERVER['P_PATH'].'assets/admin1/js/layout.js"></script>';
    return $str;
}

public function getActiveHeader():string{
    return "Dashboard";

}

public function getPluginInitialization():string{

    $str = "<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            Layout.init();
            });
            </script>";
    return $str;

}

public function getGoogleAnalytics():string{
    $str = "";
    return $str;
}

public function getHeaderKey():string{
    return "Dashboard";
}

public function getFooter():string{
     $str = '';
    return $str;
}}
```

`
Thank you for your help in advance.

Raphael Scheinkoenig

Comment: Where did you put `View.php`? Share your folder's tree.

Comment: added the tree of the libary above

Comment: Then you may want use `psr-4` instead of `psr-0`. Change it in your composer.json file, and rebuild the autoloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `psr-0`, you should put `RaphaelScheinkoenig\WebLib\View` *(View.php)* into `src/RaphaelScheinkoenig/WebLib` folder.

Fyi, `psr-0` has been marked as deprecated. So, just use `psr-4`. And if you use `psr-4` you don't need to make `src/RaphaelScheinkoenig/WebLib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the autoloading configuration in `composer.json` to use PSR-4 instead of PSR-0 (as already suggested in the comments):

```
{
    "name": "raphaelscheinkoenig/weblib",
    "description": "WebLib",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Raphael Scheinkoenig",
            "email": "scheinkoenig.raphael@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "RaphaelScheinkoenig\\WebLib\\": "src/"
         }
     } 
}
```

For reference, see

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24869629/1172545